# How to store cron time expression on MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cron

I'm using this [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) library.

And i want to store this expression to MySQL.

Any suggestions on best practice to store this library cron time expression in a DB ?

For examples.

```
# At 10 minutes
* 10 * * * *

# Every 10 minutes
0 */10 * * * *

# At midnight
00 00 00 * * *

# Available Cron patterns
Asterisk. E.g. *
Ranges. E.g. 1-3,5
Steps. E.g. */2

# And Cron Ranges
Seconds: 0-59
Minutes: 0-59
Hours: 0-23
Day of Month: 1-31
Months: 0-11 (Jan-Dec)
Day of Week: 0-6 (Sun-Sat)
```

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting this format ('* 10 * * * *')  from user. Or we want to generate based on user input afterwards we needs make the format and store?

Comment: @Win Hi! I want to generate myself is just for scheduler !

Comment: How user will give the input?

Comment: Like this ! `0 */10 * * * *`

Comment: You can store as a string. That's enough. Is this make any problem?

Comment: I want to know `byte` size. is it need to 10bytes or something else

Comment: 30bytes enough, Each * can be replaced only with 4 bytes max

Comment: @Win I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

You should design by keeping in mind what cron can take in.

```
0 10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * *
```

is used to do something at 10 hours to 22 hours every 2 hours. Likewise some list may come for month, day, etc. So, do not shrink too much. Just create a string of sufficient length to start with. And later after accumulating lot of data, you shall go by the data.